# Add callback url after customer like page via Facebook Pagebox Event

Tags: facebook

I'm working with the Facebook Pagebox plugin which can be found in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/?locale=vi_VN.

[image]

After researching, I have done showing the pagebox on my website. But not only showing pagebox i also want to add a callback link to make facebook send a request to my callback link after client-like page via the embedded pagebox. Can we do it?

Comment: No you can not.

Comment: Hi WizKid, why do you know? And do you any other solutions for this requirement? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to know?